# Easiest way to redirect serial port to a file BUT only 1 (last) line at once?

Tags: linux, networking, serial-port

I've got a digital scale that outputs the current weight over RS232. (continuously, 1 line)
(e.g.: "     10.13 kg\n")

I want to make the value accessible via network using the Raspberry Pi.
So just a simple html file should hold the last value/line of the serial output.

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 > scale_value.html
```

would let the file grow and grow.

Is there any Linux guru out there who can tell me how to do this in an "easy and lightweight" way?

Answer (score 0):

This line should work:

```
while true ; do $(head /dev/ttyS0 > scale_value.html) ; sleep 5 ; done
```

see also [How to run scripts every 5 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800/how-to-run-scripts-every-5-seconds-using-cron) for more infos about this and how to add functionality to stop this script remotely.